# Qunit fail with TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I have a ember app. Everything works expect one acceptance test :

```
test('delete user 271', function(assert) {
  server.logging = true;
  server.create('user', {id: 271});
  visit('/users/271');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/users/271');
    const deleteUSerButton = find(':button.delete-user');
    click(deleteUSerButton);
    andThen(() => assert.equal(find('.modal-body').text().trim(), 'Are you sure you want to remove this user ?'));
  });
});
```

But I get `TypeError: $ is not a function : at didInsertElement (actionnable-modal.js:10)`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    let modalContainer = $('#modal-container .modal');
    modalContainer.modal();
    modalContainer.on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
      this.dismiss();
    }); // line 10
  }
});
```

The problem the test fail randomly. I don't know why. I removed the `/temp` folder without success. It seems that `jquery.noConflict()` is a mess for my code but if I remove this line : `TypeError: modalContainer.modal is not a function` and it breaks my modal on my website.

Do you how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is because I'm loading some assets with ember-cli-rails, assets are not serve for ember tests.

I had to add jquery + bootstrap.js script into my `emberApp/tests/index.html`.

Now it's work but it's not a good way of doing it. I should not use bootstrap but make my own modal without bootstrap. I should use only ember with correct addons or own code.